# In React when using Firebase, should getAuth getStorage getFirestore etc be called once and passed around, or can they be called in each component?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

If I need to use the result of `const db = getFirestore()` or `const auth = getAuth(app)` etc in multiple components, should I:

1. Rewrite those lines `const db = getFirestore()` or `const auth = getAuth(app)` etc in every component whenever I need them, or
2. Call them just one at the top level in the App component, and then pass them to child components as props, to avoid multiple calls?

I feel option 1 is easier to code, but may incur a performance penalty. What is the correct way of doing this in React/Firebase coding?

Comment: [Questions asking for best practices](https://overflow.tips/problematic-questions#what-is-the-besteasiestfastest-way-to-do-x) are generally understood as seeking opinions, which is off-topic for Stack Overflow and likely to be [closed](https://overflow.tips/why-question-closed#opinion-based-and-seeking-recommendations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getFirestore(...)`, `getAuth(...)` and similar calls are all simple local-only calls that initialize some basic objects from the configuration. There is little harm in calling them in multiple places.

That said, I'd recommend passing the `app` to either all of them or to none of them, unlike what the code in your question does now.

So either get all services from the default app:

```
const db = getFirestore();
const auth = getAuth();
```

**or** get all of them from a specified app:

```
const db = getFirestore(app);
const auth = getAuth(app);
```

But not a mix of these.